# Reading template files and connecting to mongodb on each node.js request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, template-engine

I'm new to node js and I've seen on tutorials how the programmer creates a connection to mongodb and reads in html templates from disk each time a request is made to the server, ie the code resides in the request event handler.

This can't possibly be the way it should be done right? The template file should be buffered into memory and the database connection should created on the startup of the server?

Comment: Sounds like a terrible tutorial to me, your assumptions on how things _should_ be are correct.

Comment: You might be misinterpreting the code, can you please provide it?

Comment: That code is in a intro to node video tutorial from tuts+. I'm seeing the same kind of mistake in a javascript book I'm reading at the moment as well, eloquent javascript, 2nd edition, good book overall but he is requiring the url module each time there's a http request, it's a better idea to require the module on server start right? Here's the code, Router.prototype.resolve http://eloquentjavascript.net/21_skillsharing.html#c_QH06ksI6zt